# Access a file outside of working directory without referencing full path

Tags: r, relative-path

This is a silly example but I am not sure how to solve this problem. Hopefully this illustrates my issue. I am working in windows 10. I have data contained in this directory:

`C:/Project/Attempt1/RCode/Data/data.txt`

If my R script is in `C:/Project/Attempt1/RCode` I can read in the data like so:

`read.table(./Data/data.txt`)

But if my data stays in the same place but I have another script here:

`C:/Project/Attempt2/RCode`

How do I access the `data.txt` file without referencing the whole path? But this doesn't work: `.Attempt1/RCode/Data/data.txt` if my working directory is `C:/Project/Attempt2/RCode`.

For sake of the question please take these three things as true:

- Don't want to duplicate `data.txt`
- Can't use full path as that part (particularly the drive) will be variable
- Can't move the data

I hope this makes sense

Comment: You can navigate "up" directories with `..`:  `read.table("../../Attempt1/RCode/Data/data.txt")`

Comment: Note that that syntax in the above comment holds for many / most programming languages and OSs (windows excluded). It is typically referred to as a relative path and is relative to the current working directory. This is in contrast to an absolute path where the full path is described.

Comment: @sirallen You should make this an answer. It is perfect for my purpopes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can navigate "up" directories with `..`. Try this:

```
dat = read.table('../../Attempt1/RCode/Data/data.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `../` to move up (or out) of the current directory. You can use `../../` to move up twice and so on as necessary.